# Flutter : Year list disappear from year selection when applying textTheme to showDatePicker() Theme

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, dialog

In my flutter application I have used a customized showDatePicker() which works fine except the year selection mode, where i can see only the 2023 year for selection and all the other years are seems hidden. Here my first date is 01/07/22 and last date is 26/09/23 so the the year 2022 & 2023 should be available for selection and all the other years should display in disabled color.The calendar mode works fine where i can choose dates on 2022.When I remove textTheme from Theme builder it works.how to make it work.Below is the screenshot.
[image: Year Selection]
[image: Calendar view - last date]
[image: Calendar view - first date]

Below is my code :

```
Future<void> _selectFromToDate(String selDate) async {
final now = findCurrentDay();   // 26/09/23
final createdDate = findCreateDate();   // 01/07/22
DateTime itemDate = selDate != '' ? ddMMyyFormat.parse(selDate) : now;
if (!mounted) return;
final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: itemDate,
  firstDate: createdDate,
  lastDate: now,
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
          primary: blueShade60,
          primaryContainer: Colors.black,
          secondaryContainer: Colors.black,
          onSecondary: Colors.black,
          onPrimary: Colors.white,
          surface: Colors.black,
          onSurface: Colors.black,
          secondary: Colors.black,
        ),
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          headlineMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),//line 2 full date
          bodyLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,),//year selection
          titleSmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0), //line 3 month year dropdown
          bodySmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,),//day selection
          labelSmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,), // line 1 , select date heading
        ),
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.red, // button text color
            textStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,)
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: child!,
    );
  },
);
if (picked != null && ddMMyyFormat.format(picked) != selDate) {
 _txtDateController.text = ddMMyyFormat.format(picked);
}
}
```